# Unable to convert from string to byte array

Tags: java, file, arrays

I'm making a wordcount program and i want to write the total number of words at the end of the file. As i'm using FileOutputStream i've to convert my string to Byte array. But i'm getting a compile time error. Please help me out with this.

```
Byte[] msg;
msg="Total Number of words are: ".getBytes();
```

and i'm getting compile time error like this:

> error: incompatible types: byte[] cannot be converted to Byte[]

and also i'm using write method and passing a byte arraylike this:

```
fout.write(msg);
```

where fout is object of fileoutputstream opened in append mode. i'm getting error like this:

> error: no suitable method found for write(Byte[]).

I've imported `java.io.*;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a noob mistake. You are using `Byte[ ]` to store the returned bytes from `String.getBytes()` method. The `getBytes()` method returns a primitive byte array not a byte object. Replace `Byte[ ]` with `byte[ ]` on left hand side. It will 100% work.

Comment: Happy to help :)  please accept the answer if it helped you .

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the primitive type `byte` and the wrapper class `Byte`

You should change your code to `byte[] msg = ...` since `String#getBytes()` returns an array of `byte` primitives