# byte or Byte, please explain

Tags: java, byte

I am creating a new `Byte` object in JAVA and using `Byte` to construct a `String` and it gives an error...

```
Byte B1 = new Byte((byte)41);
String S1 = new String(B1);
```

But, no issue when I use `byte` instead of `Byte`

```
byte d[]= {65,48};
String s1 = new String(d);
```

what is the difference?

Comment: As for OP's problem, the big difference here is that one snippet has an array and one doesn't.

Comment: Refer to my answer here to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036726/unable-to-convert-from-string-to-byte-array/38036766#38036766

Comment: You are not passing a `byte` argument in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the `new String(byte[])` case there is a suitable constructor overload, and in the `new String(Byte)` case there isn't.

Why is that?

- Because that is the way it was designed.
- Because of what the constructors are designed to do.
- Because the Java designers think that it is generally speaking a bad idea to clutter up the APIs with constructor and method overloads to deal with variants that will *rarely* be used.

How should you find out more?  For example, what constructors does a type have?  What do they do / mean?

- By reading the javadocs!

---

By the way, auto-unboxing / widening are not relevant to this example. There is no `String(byte)` or `String(Byte)` ... or `String(Object)` constructor.  No amount of unboxing or widening is going to make this example work.

And to illustrate that `new String(...)` does not work with a `byte` ...

```
public class Test {
    String s = new String((byte) 42);
}
$ javac Test.java 
Test.java:2: error: no suitable constructor found for String(byte)
    String s = new String((byte) 42);
               ^
    constructor String.String(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; byte cannot be converted to String)
    constructor String.String(char[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; byte cannot be converted to char[])
    constructor String.String(byte[]) is not applicable                                                                                                       
      (argument mismatch; byte cannot be converted to byte[])                                                                                                 
    constructor String.String(StringBuffer) is not applicable                                                                                                 
      (argument mismatch; byte cannot be converted to StringBuffer)                                                                                           
    constructor String.String(StringBuilder) is not applicable                                                                                                
      (argument mismatch; byte cannot be converted to StringBuilder)                                                                                          
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output                                                                   
1 error                                                                       
$
```

Comment: @glee8e - Actually, it does explain things ... with more generality, and at a much deeper level than a simple answer to the (bad) question.  If the reader reads (and understands) this Answer, they will know how to answer their original question and a whole class of other questions as well.

Comment: Auto-unboxing / widening are not relevant to this example.  There is no `String(byte)` or `String(Byte)` ... or `String(Object)` constructor.

Comment: Well, my fault. I once thought there is some constructor that takes an int as param... I messed String with StringBuilder which has an int constructor. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the biggest difference is that in one case, you're using an array, and in the other case, you're not.

However, it's worth pointing out that there would be a difference even if you used an array in both cases.  That is:

```
Byte[] d1 = {65,48};         // legal
byte[] d2 = {65,48};         // legal
String s1 = new String(d1);  // illegal
String s2 = new String(d2);  // legal
```

(Note: It's preferable to say `Byte[] d1` instead of `Byte d1[]`; the two are equivalent, but the first one makes it clear that `Byte[]` is the type of the variable, while the second one was included in Java only as a concession to C programmers who were using to writing things that way.)

The point here is that Java will autobox and autounbox `Byte` and `byte`.  That is, if you have a `Byte` variable and assign a `byte` to it, it will convert automatically, and vice versa.  However, this autoboxing and autounboxing doesn't apply to arrays--Java **won't** automatically convert between `Byte[]` and `byte[]`.

Unfortunately, I don't see a simple way to convert between the two array types, except by using Apache Commons which has `toObject` and `toPrimitive` array conversions (see [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Byte[]))).

Answer (score -2):

This is because the way autoboxing and unboxing works. Here you can get more information: http://beginnersbook.com/2014/09/java-autoboxing-and-unboxing-with-examples/

Comment: Incorrect.  Autoboxing & unboxing are not relevant to this example.  (Hint: there is no `String(byte)` constructor.  Really.  Read the javadocs!)

Comment: IMO, there's not enough here to warrant an answer. This could easily be a comment since it's entirely supported by the link. Please provide the gist of the information in that link; it could die and this will be surely worthless then.